# How to get Gradle version matching with an Artifactory Gradle Repository

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

I have a Gradle Repository set up in Artifactory 5.0.

I can reference dependencies in my gradle/java project using exact versions, e.g. `my.org:my-pkg:1.2.10`, however gradle doesn't find them if I want to use version matching e.g. `my.org:my-pkg:1.2.+`.

This works with other packages in other sources for example spring, mockito etc, but not with my artifacts in my Artifactory.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.
Did you upload (deploy) the `my-pkg-1.2.10.pom` file as well?

When using dynamic versions (with `+`), gradle uses the `maven-metadata.xml` file to find the latest version. This file is created (under `my/org/my-pkg`) only when the pom files are present.